# aws s3 copy failing with fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: cp, aws, amazon-s3

Copying a file from S3 bucket to EC2 Instance.EC2 Instance is in the same region us-east-2 as S3 Bucket in.S3 Bucket is ACL disabled and Allowed for public access.

```bash
# /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp s3://Bucket_name/Trail_SW/server_dec.tar.gz /tmp --source-region us-east-2
fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

```bash
/usr/local/bin/aws --version  
aws-cli/2.11.16 Python/3.11.3 Linux/4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64 exe/x86_64.rhel.8 prompt/off
```

Please share any suggestions.

Comment: as the error says, you don't have permission to do what you want.

Comment: Frist you'd need to know what Policy applies on that bucket. You need at least the following permissions:`s3:ListBucket`,  `s3:GetObject`  and for the `copy` part you'd need the `s3:PutObject`  perimissions to upload your object to the destination bucket. See  https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/radosgw/bucketpolicy/ for more

Comment: Why would you need PutObject to cp to a local path? Shouldn't that just be a GetObject?